# Does calling big functions make code slower?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have a function which 1200 lines long, with a simple syntax like this:

```
def Parse(self, T1, T2, data):
    if T1==1:
        if T2==1:
        #do something
        #do so many thing
    elif T1==2:
        if T2==1:
        #do something
```

Is it bad for performance? I'm using this function 1000~ times per second

Is this better?

```
def Parse(self, T1, T2, data):
    if T1==1:
        if T2==1:
        #function(data)
    elif T1==2:
        if T2==1:
        #function(data)
```

Comment: Are you actually having a performance issue? Have you done any profiling? Is this really the bottleneck? Have you considered AB testing if so?

Comment: when i have 1.5k concurrent user cpu usage almost %100
i'm using gevent i tought when switch saving opcodes and there is a lot opcode in 1k line

Comment: What makes you think the time isn't being spent on the lines that *are* being executed?